# Anaconda I cannot switch environment without error JAVA_HOME.sh = not found?

Tags: java, anaconda

This problem is driving me nuts. Upon trying to switch environments:

```
(base) <user> ~ % conda activate charm
/Users/<user>/opt/anaconda3/envs/charm/etc/conda/activate.d/java_home.sh:6: = not found
(charm) <user>@x86_64-apple-darwin13 ~ %
```

The environment does seem to change but I have no idea why I get the error. Any ideas how to fix this??

EDIT: Contents of JAVA_Home.sh

```
export CONDA_BACKUP_JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_HOME}"
export JAVA_HOME="${CONDA_PREFIX}"

export CONDA_BACKUP_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

if [ $(uname) == Darwin ]; then
  export JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}"/jre/lib/server
else
  if [ $(uname -m) == x86_64 ]; then
    export JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}"/jre/lib/amd64/server
  else
    export JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}"/jre/lib/i386/server
  fi
fi
```

Comment: what is the content of /Users/<user>/opt/anaconda3/envs/charm/etc/conda/activate.d/java_home.sh

Comment: Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60183391/edit) and add the content to the post itself.

Comment: Could this be related to wrong Java JDK installed? I have Java 8 installed.

Comment: I think this is due to `==` not being compatible with every shell. For zsh and bash compatibility it should be `if [ $(uname) = Darwin ]; then`. Check where you got the java package from and report this as a bug.

Comment: @cel - you might be correct as trying to switch envs in bash returns: `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.`

Answer (score -1):

```
export CONDA_BACKUP_JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_HOME}"
export JAVA_HOME="${CONDA_PREFIX}"

export CONDA_BACKUP_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

if [ $(uname) "==" "Darwin" ]; then
  export JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}"/jre/lib/server
else
  if [ $(uname -m) "==" "x86_64" ]; then
    export JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}"/jre/lib/amd64/server
  else
    export JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}"/jre/lib/i386/server
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.